# opening a dataset through URL on WEKA

Tags: dataset, weka, data-mining, kaggle

I have found some good datasets to work on from *kaggle* and I've tried copying the URL of the page to open it inside the WEKA program but still nothing works.

This might sound dumb but I only want to know how to open it through URL. I know it's easier to open from file but does the "open URL" work? I have tried uploading the datasets on my driver and it gave me the same result after pasting the URL path on WEKA

> "No suitable URLSourcedLoader found for URL!"

[image: Couldn't read from URL - photo]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to invoke a dataset into your URL

I mean : 
http://storm.cis.fordham.edu/~gweiss/data-mining/weka-data/xxx

xxx = Then simply add the filename at the end of this string (e.g., "iris.arff")

Try this, both on a web page and Weka to understand what is required to work properly

cheers